# Macos buttons turn gray when the accent colour is graphite

Tags: macos, themes

is there any method to keep the colored button when using the graphite mode? I've didn't seen any guide or help on the forums so i was wonder if there is any way of doing that

Comment: 'Graphite mode' is basically "grey highlights" on top of Dark Mode. If you want a different colour… pick a different colour.

Comment: So there is no method to keep the colored lights high when using the graphite mode? I really like the gray details when I use the dark mode (always) but the gray buttons are a bit sad and it's easier to see which window is selected with the colored ones